# Can the .mca region files alone be loaded into a playable Minecraft world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been using Bobby for a while, and I've noticed it stores data into .mca files. I figured I could use them to load the world from a server in single-player. I tried generating a new world and replacing its region files, but Minecraft seemed to just regenerate the chunks once I loaded back into the world. I also tried creating a superflat world with no layers in hopes that there would be no auto-generation, but that didn't work either.

Is there a way to load those files as a playable Minecraft world on 1.19.2?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. But the problem is that you will have to remember the coordinates of the region to see it. Otherwise, it will get loaded in your world, but you will not be able to see the region until you go to the specific coordinates.

Also, the .mca world generation files should be of the world/server created in the same Minecraft version in which you are trying to load them.

You can try these steps:

1. Generate a new world.
2. As the loading completes, exit before the chunks load (or it will cause reloading of chunks resulting in weird world generation).
3. Copy your .mca file into the newly created world folder.(I am assuming that you know how to do it)
4. If it says **Do you want overwrite the files**, just do **Copy and Replace**.
5. Done. Enjoy the imported region.

**NOTE:** You WILL have to remember the coords of the region.